# Selenium: Clicking CheckBox failing with ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a modal div visible on the screen with a list of checkboxes.  In debug mode, I can manually click the checkbox.  But via automation, clicking the checkbox fails with a ElementNotVisibleException.  Additionally, if I check the Displayed property, it's false and if I look at the computed CSS, display = none.

The code that's isolating the checkbox looks like this:

```
var panelCheckBox = tds[2].FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
panelCheckBox.Click();
```

Why is the element being calculated as not visible when I can see it and manually check it (and then see in code that the checked property changed)?

Comment: Some other element is setting the state of the `input`.  You need to figure out what that is, and click that element.

Comment: use a better and specific selector.

Comment: @Richard, the structure is this: <td><a><input/></a></td>.  I've tried clicking the <a> and the <td> but neither work.  Any ideas on how to track down what is setting the state?

Comment: @Saifur, the selector is not the problem.  It grabs the correct element as there is only one input element beneath the td.

Comment: Do a `var panelCheckBoxes = tds[2].FindElements(By.TagName("input"));` **NOTICE  FindElements** to see how many elements your selector returns just to make sure selenium is not looking at some hidden element there

Comment: @Saifur, there's 3, two have child input elements and BOTH are visible in the UI but are failing in automation.  The third does not have any children.

Comment: So you decide which one is the target element. If you can post your html snippet I can help you with writing the selector

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Selenium won't click an element that has display:none attribute set.  Even though it was actually visible in the UI,  Selenium wouldn't touch it.

Discovered that there was an empty sibling `<label>` element to the input element that was catching the click event by firing up Firefox and the Selenium IDE extension and recording what Selenium said was being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it helps, you can use IJavascriptExecutor to click on an "invisible" element. For selenium it might be a check if element is visible or not but firing a Javascript always works.

So in your case it can be something like :

```
var js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

 if (js != null)
{
    js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('t2').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();") 
}
```